# Web Deployment Tool on Win2k8 R2

Tags: windows, iis

I'm trying to install Web Deployment Tool on Win2k8 R2, but always fail with the next error:

```
MSI (s) (D4:20) [16:53:38:151]: Created Custom Action Server with PID 3780 (0xEC4). 
MSI (s) (D4:FC) [16:53:38:182]: Running as a service.
MSI (s) (D4:FC) [16:53:38:182]: Hello, I'm your 32bit Elevated Non-remapped custom action server. Error 1720. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A script required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Custom action InstallEtwManifest script error -2146827859, Microsoft VBScript runtime error: ActiveX component can't create object: 'oLocator.ConnectServer' Line 9, Column 13,  
MSI (s) (D4:18) [16:53:47:371]: Product: Microsoft Web Deploy 3.6 -- Error 1720. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A script required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Custom action InstallEtwManifest script error -2146827859, Microsoft VBScript runtime error: ActiveX component can't create object: 'oLocator.ConnectServer' Line 9, Column 13,
MSI (s) (D4:18) [16:53:47:371]: Closing MSIHANDLE (121) of type 0 for thread 2584 
MSI (s) (D4:18) [16:53:47:371]: Closing MSIHANDLE (120) of type 790536 for thread 4764 Action ended 16:53:49: InstallFinalize. Return value 3. 
MSI (s) (D4:9C) [16:53:49:836]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0 
MSI (s) (D4:9C) [16:53:49:836]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
```

(This is not all the LOG file.)

I also try to install in another Win2k8 R2 (this one without IIS I Think) everything works without any problem.

Also, I got procmon saves of a good and bad version and trying to get some info from there.

I spend the whole day trying to install this app, search with our friend google, a lot of posts but nothing solves the problem, 8h and not even a different error.

Thanks in advance for everyone.

Comment: I dont think, my problem is installing a .msi software called WebDeployTool.

And that post is related to IIS aplications right? 
Im not yet playing with the migration, because I cant even install the software.

Comment: Have you checked whether that update has been installed? If it's just started happening I would be surprised if it's not linked.

Comment: DId now, just to clear my mind
This a production Web Server, I dont install any update before test in test and dev system.